# How to get "Web page" contact field through Exchange EWS/EWS managed api?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, extended-properties

I'm trying to extract contacts from exchange using EWS managed api.
I've managed to find Property tags of almost all the fields through [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765838.aspx).

Still there are some fields I'm not able to get. The main one is the field "Web Page". Is this field available as some other name because searching for this through the list of Property tags in the above link is not matching any.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get/set the PidTagBusinessHomePage extended property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842385(v=office.12).aspx eg

```
  ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BUSINESS_HOME_PAGE = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A51, MapiPropertyType.String);
  Contact.SetExtendedProperty(PR_BUSINESS_HOME_PAGE,"http://blahblahlblah.com");
```

or

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_BUSINESS_HOME_PAGE = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x3A51, MapiPropertyType.String);
        PropertySet psContactPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        psContactPropSet.Add(PR_BUSINESS_HOME_PAGE);
        Contact Contact = Contact.Bind(service,Id,psContactPropSet)
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: But "Web Page" and "Business Home Page" are two different fields.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869847.aspx) is a link which says so. The problem is I'm not able to find any identifier for "Web page" field.

Comment: Well there are actually 3 properties that could refer to the WebPage see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203761(v=exchg.80).aspx . There is no underlying WebPage Property if shown like in that page you reference  that will be an abstraction of one the three properties in that link i posted. My suggestion is you use a Mapi editor like Outlookspy or MFCMapi to look at the underlying properties that have been set on an  Item. This will let you see all the properties that have been set  Also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218401(v=exchg.80).aspx properly explains it better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful.